# Not able to select suggestion list value using onFocus and onBlur in react input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm showing suggestions list on the focus of input field and hiding on clicking outside.

List show and hide is working **`onFocus`** and **`onBlur`** of input field but not able to select any list value from dropdown list. when I try to select, it's hiding dropdown list without selecting clicked list item.

After removing **`onBlur`** method, I'm able to select value from the dropdown list but can't achieve another scenario - hiding dropdown list by clicking anywhere.

Sample code

```
function Suggestion() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [suggestion, setShowSuggestion] = useState(false);
  const typeSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setShowSuggestion(true);
  };
  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setShowSuggestion(false);
  };
  const setToInput = (selected) => {
    setSearch(selected);
    setShowSuggestion(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        types="text"
        value={search}
        onChange={typeSearch}
        placeholder="Type something"
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
      {suggestion && (
        <div className="list">
          {["List 1", "List 2", "List 3"].map((list) => (
            <p onClick={()=>setToInput(list)} key={list}>
              {list}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I achieve both scenarios by updating/correcting code?

Please help me to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

because you're calling `setShowSuggestion(false);` onBlur which hide the list whenever you click the list the input call blur event.

```
 <div className="App">
  <input
    types="text"
    value={search}
    onChange={typeSearch}
    placeholder="Type something"
    onFocus={handleFocus}
   //remove this
   //onBlur={handleBlur}
  />
  {suggestion && (
    <div className="list">
      {["List 1", "List 2", "List 3"].map((list) => (
        <p onClick={()=>
             {
             setToInput(list)
             // you call handleBlur after your select
              handleBlur()
              }} key={list}>
          {list}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```